# How do I view the Call Hierarchy window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx), I should be able to highlight a procedure name, right muse click and select "Call Hierarchy" menu to open the Call Hierarchy window.

Yet, there is no context sensitive menu available when I highlight a routine.

What gives?

Comment: The file also needs to be open inside a project for the language service to be able to determine the call hierarchy.  Also, what language are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:
1.  Call Hierarchy is only available in Pro and above
2.  Call Hierarchy is only currently available in C#

Assuming those two things are true for you it sounds like you may have a binding problem or something else going on.  Go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and type in "View.CallHierarchy" in the "Show commands containing" textbox.  See what is listed in the "Shortcuts for selected command" drop down list.

Comment: Ah. I am using VB.NET. So much or Microsoft's commitment to making sure that VB.NEt is not a 2nd class citizen. I'm overdue for switching.

Comment: In VS 2012 this function will be available for VB.NET users too. Meanwhile next best thing is 'Find Symbol', shift-F12. A list of symbol usage is shown. When you click a membername and press shift-F12, you will see.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Resharper installed, it could be hiding it as well.

Untick the checkbox in ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items.

Comment: Thanks for this! I figured it was an extension hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

I have VS 2010 Prof and see the menu option. Make sure your cursor is on a method. Also Shortcut key is: Ctrl K, Ctrl T

Comment: "The key combination (ctl K, ctl K) is bound to command (View Call Hierarchy) which is not currently available.

Comment: @xaml-toe, what edition of VS are you on ? Some editions might have this disabled.

Comment: ChadD you get that message if you haven't highlighted a method.